pip install chroma-hnswlib
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:D:\soft-engg-project-may-2024-se-may-22-main\venv\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\libs /LIBPATH:C:\Users\naveen\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313 /LIBPATH:D:\soft-engg-project-may-2024-se-may-22-main\venv\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.42.34433\lib\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_hnswlib build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\./python_bindings/bindings.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\hnswlib.cp313-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-313\Release\./python_bindings\hnswlib.cp313-win_amd64.lib
      LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.42.34433\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit code 1104
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for chroma-hnswlib
Failed to build chroma-hnswlib
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (chroma-hnswlib)

"I tried installing the chroma-hnswlib library using the command pip install chroma-hnswlib. I expected the library to install successfully and be usable in my project. However, during the installation, the process failed with a LNK1104 error, stating that it couldn't open the file kernel32.lib. I suspect this might be related to missing build tools or a configuration issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it."

Looking at the available wheels for chroma-hnswlib on PyPi, there is none for Python 3.13. Infact, there's no wheel for Python 3.12 on Windows (your OS).
To use this package on a Windows machine, you might have to use Python 3.11 as there are wheels for Windows x86-64 machines.
